# Configuration management for selected servers

Tags: apache-zookeeper, salt-stack, configuration-management

i want to manage configuration for selected linux servers from one application.
there is zookeeper but it change the configuration for all servers

is there a solution to specify a group of servers to edit configuration to?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the salt grains to add a role like "zookeeper" on your hosts that you want to manage. Then when you need to update the config you can target like "salt -G 'roles:zookeeper' state.sls some.config".

Or if you can't match on that you can also target partial hostnames or if you set the app name as a grain you can target that.

Comment: thank you i was already in that direction of salt management but now i want to have multi master with salt but in case of failure i want zookeeper to backup the masters is this possible?